# send a object as a paramatre in an onclick function

Tags: onclick

${post.author.username == userId.username ? 'Edit' : ''}

hello , can someone help me with fixing this error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkxDA.jpg)

i'm trying to use un onclick function inside a button and send an object as a paramatre